# How to use interceptor with Spring AMQP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Is there a way to intercept messages once template.convertAndSend is called, before the message is delivered to RabbitMQ.

Also any way to intercept the message before reaching the handler?

I can handle the message using PostProcessor for publisher, but prefer to use interceptor.

```
public class TestPostProcessor implements MessagePostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    Tracer defaultTracer;

    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
        //.....
        //.... 
        return message;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `>I can handle the message using PostProcessor for publisher, but prefer to use interceptor.` Can you explain what you mean by that? The MPP __is__ a form of interceptor. The listener container also supports MPPs after receiving and before delivery to the listener: `setAfterReceivePostProcessors()`.

Comment: To use it I had to do rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(routingKey,"Message",postProcessor); - was wondering if there is a way to inject this, without us having to provide it here.  Also how would we do it on SimpleMessageListenerContainer ?

Comment: Yes; see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MessagePostProcessor` is a form of interceptor.

There are two ways to invoke one - use one of the overloaded `convertAndSend()` methods that take an MPP as an argument, or add one or more to the `RabbitTemplate` using `setBeforePublishPostProcessors()`.

You can also intercept received messages using the `setAfterReceivePostProcessors()` which is invoked before the received message is returned from a `receive()` method.

The listener container also supports MPPs after receiving and before delivery to the listener via its `setAfterReceivePostProcessors()` method.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using spring boot properties (from org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitProperties) in your application.properties file, you can provide your own RabbitListenerContainerFactory :

```
  @Bean
  public CustomRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
      SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MyContextMessageProcessor messageProcessor) {
    CustomRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new CustomRabbitListenerContainerFactory(messageProcessor);
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
  }
```

CustomRabbitListenerContainerFactory.java :

```
public class CustomRabbitListenerContainerFactory
  extends org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory {

  private MessagePostProcessor[] messagePostProcessor;

  public CustomRabbitListenerContainerFactory(MessagePostProcessor... messagePostProcessor) {
    super();
    this.messagePostProcessor = messagePostProcessor;
  }

  @Override
  protected void initializeContainer(SimpleMessageListenerContainer instance, RabbitListenerEndpoint endpoint) {
    super.initializeContainer(instance, endpoint);
    instance.addAfterReceivePostProcessors(messagePostProcessor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Even simpler solution: just autowire the framework created SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory (pay attention for the Direct part of the story) and call the method: setAfterReceivePostProcessors